# get the content of hardcoded memory address in C++

Tags: c++, memory-address

```
double address = 3068770752;
std::string hello = (char *)address;
```

**error: invalid cast from type 'double' to type 'char*'**

So, if i use type long or int, this works, but with type double, this is not working.
how can i do this?

Thanks!

EDIT: i'm programming a PHP extension in C++, this is a "content "of a custom function "get_memory_data(double address)", in php you uses:

```
<?php
$a = "hello";
$b = get_memaddress($a); //0x123456
$c = hextodec($b); //3068770752
$d = get_memdata($c); //hello
```

Comment: By casting to an `int` before casting to a `char*`... what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Cornstalks: Fractional addresses, of course: More than platform 9, but not quite platform 10.

Comment: What are you really trying to do here?  What is the string for?

Comment: Let us not condone statically storing a pointer without knowing the reason!

Comment: To clarify, can `address` ever be negative?

Comment: You gave the most obvious answer: declare `address` as an `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast it to an integer first:

```
char * p = reinterpret_cast<char *>(static_cast<uintptr_t>(address));

std::string i_cause_undefined_behaviour(p);
```

Comment: Why `uintptr_t`? What's so special about that type? Why not use `int*`?

Comment: @David: Only `uintptr_t` is guaranteed to have the correct size. (Or perhaps `intptr_t`.) It's an integral type, not a pointer type.

Comment: @David `uintptr_t` is not a "pointer to int." It's an "integral type large enough to hold any pointer."

Comment: i have the same problem using the static_cast: invalid static_cast from type 'uintptr_t' to type 'char*

Comment: @felix46r: Yeah, sorry, it should have been a `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't make sense to store a memory address in a double, that's not the reason the compiler won't let you but it's certainly not helping. On a 64-bit platforms you need 64-bits to accurately store a memory address, but a double can only hold 53-bits of precision.

If you want to hard code a memory address you should store it in a uintptr_t.